# Problema con la API de google translate, no funciona en android 8 y 7 pero si en android 9

Tags: java, android-studio, google-api

Al usar mi código en Android 9 funciona a la perfección pero si lo uso en 8 y 7 me sale el siguiente error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.secuencia.saz.kualifyplus, PID: 23507
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method decodeBase64(Ljava/lang/String;)[B in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
>           at com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:101)
>           at com.google.api.client.util.PemReader.readNextSection(PemReader.java:106)
>           at com.google.api.client.util.PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(PemReader.java:135)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.privateKeyFromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:296)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromPkcs8(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:286)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:210)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:174)
>           at com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:141)
>           at com.secuencia.saz.kualifyplus.PantallaReating.getTranslateService(PantallaReating.java:429)
>           at com.secuencia.saz.kualifyplus.PantallaReating.onCreate(PantallaReating.java:173)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6948)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3042)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1639)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6780)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote

Mi código:

```
public void getTranslateService() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try (InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.kualify)) {

        //Get credentials:
   //aqui me marca el erorror //
 final GoogleCredentials myCredentials =GoogleCredentials.fromStream(is);


        //Set credentials and get translate service:
        TranslateOptions translateOptions = TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(myCredentials).build();
        translate = translateOptions.getService();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que el mensaje de error hace referencia a un método que no existe o es inaccesible:

> No static method decodeBase64

Busca este método en tu código si tu lo escribiste y fíjate si fue modificado o borrado. Si no, entonces es un método que proviene desde otra librería que solo funciona en android 9, probablemente de apache; es probable que la librería de google que estas usando sea únicamente pera android 9 o no tiene los permisos necesarios para correr en versiones de android inferior.

Supondría que aprendiste a usar esta librería de google desde la documentación oficial, si es así, mira los logs de cambios, puede que haya información útil sobre como utilizarlo en android 9 que sea diferente para otras versiones y es probable que estes usando la guía de uso para android 9, mas no la que debes usar.

Tambien puedes intentar utilizar estos metodos para que tu código los use en lugar de los que se supone que trata de utilizar, pero no puedo asegurar que funcione:

```
private static byte[] decodeBase64(String dataToDecode)
{
    byte[] dataDecoded = Base64.decode(dataToDecode, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return dataDecoded;
}

private static byte[] encodeBase64(byte[] dataToEncode)
{
    byte[] dataEncoded = Base64.encode(dataToEncode, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return dataEncoded;
}
```